# Curl returning (52) with AWS + uWSGI + NGinx + Pyramid setup

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, pyramid, uwsgi

Been having this issue for days and hope someone will shed a light on it.

Basically I have set up a pyramid app using AWS EC2 with uWSGI and NGinx.

I have no issue with telnet as shown below:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3003
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Next when I tried curl, it showed the below result:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:3003
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

My production.ini file:

```
###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:uwsgi#main
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 3003

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.6-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, fruler

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console

[logger_fruler]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = fruler

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s


[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3003
virtualenv = /home/ec2-user/env
die-on-term = 1
master = 1
daemonize = /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/uwsgi.log
pidfile = /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/pid_5000.pid
processes = 4

harakiri = 30
harakiri-verbose = true
limit-post = 5242880
post-buffering = 8192
```

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        #listen          <aws.ip.address>:80;
        listen 80;
        server_name     ec2-<aws.ip.address>.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com;
        #index           index.html index.htm index.py;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/<domain>.com.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/<domain>.com.error;
        root            /home/ec2-user/;
        charset         utf-8;

    location / {
            uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:3003;
            #proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3003;
            include     uwsgi_params;
        }

        location /static {
            root        /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/fruler/;
        }
    }
}
```

After running the following command:

```
$ sudo ./bin/uwsgi --ini-paste-logged FRuler/production.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from FRuler/production.ini
```

The log file for uwsgi is as followed:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Sun May  8 21:58:22 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) on 05 May 2016 01:48:35
os: Linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015
nodename: ip-172-31-29-104.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ec2-user/env
writing pidfile to /home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/pid_5000.pid
detected binary path: /home/ec2-user/env/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
your processes number limit is 3824
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:3003 fd 3
Python version: 3.4.1 (default, May  5 2016, 01:34:21)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]
Set PythonHome to /home/ec2-user/env
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xf78820
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 404800 bytes (395 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Loading paste environment: config:/home/ec2-user/env/FRuler/production.ini
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xf78820 pid: 15848 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 15848)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 15852, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 15853, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 15854, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 15855, cores: 1)
```

I entered my AWS url into the browser and it show a 502 bad gateway error.

Is there anything in the config file that I edited wrongly?

Comment: your telnet doesn't look right - can you type stuff or does it close the connection immediately?

Comment: For the telnet, it will wait a while before closing the connection. As for curl $ curl -L 127.0.0.1:3003
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: yes but with telnet if the connection is successful you should be able to type stuff, eg GET /.  Sounds like telnet is also not working.

Comment: hm... then where did I get the config wrong for nginx.conf / production.ini?

Comment: I think the configuration format has changed from what I can see from the examples you should use http-socket = :3003
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html

Comment: @webjunkie thanks, I'll give that a try